# Synchronizing multiple PR on multiple Gît repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules, multiple-repositories

My team is working on multiple microservices using Bitbucket Server. Each microservice resides in its own repository.

Let's assume you have a marketing feature that involves modifying 5 microservices to achieve the wanted requirement. The developer will have to run 5 PR (one for each microservice). If only 3 from these PR are okay, you don't want him to merge anything, but you want him to wait until the 5 ones are okay, and then merge everything at the same time, to avoid inconsistencies.

Bitbucket does not provide a scenario where one wants to have a "root" PR that depends on multiple children PR for each microservice.
The idea behind that would be to merge everything at the same time by syncing the children PR, and once they are all accepted, merge them in one shot.

I didn't find a way to do that.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is the use case that requires you to do that? Why not just submit PR's in each repository and handle them separately?

Comment: I've updated my question to give an use case ;-)

Comment: The reason there is no good support for doing this is that it's not the right way to go about your use case. What you should do instead is test each microservice and release the changes to production, behind a feature toggle. To actually *release* the feature to your customers you enable the feature toggle and all the services get the new stuff at the same time.

Comment: If you rely on merging to release, all it takes is for one of the deployment pipelines for one of the services to hickup and you're out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be : create a "root project", which contains all microservices as submodules.

A merge request on that project would consist in merging "that version for service1", "that version for service2", ...

Comment: In fact I'm still using submodules today and I do have such a root project with submodules inside. 
Assuming you have 5 PR on 5 repos, 3 are good, 2 does not pass, what would prevent someone from merging only that 3 good ones and then having an inconsistency because Microservice A v.1.0 (PR not good) does not fit well with Microservice B v1.1 (PR good) ?

Comment: ok : look into hooks that trigger on Merge Requests then ; you should be able to set up a hook, which checks that your conditions are valid, and which prevents merging that MR if it fails